# Is there a term to define when the divisor does not yield a remainder?

Tags: number-theory, terminology

Is there a term to define when a quotient is an integer value?

Example:

```
4/2 = 2 # True
5/2 = 2.5 # False
```

Comment: Why would you downvote this question? Just curious.

Comment: $4$ is a multiple of $2$.  $2$ is a divisor of $4$.  $5$ is not a multiple of $2$ and $2$ is not a divisor of $5$.

Comment: One reason could have been your use of tag. The tag you used was for a particular algebraic structure which isn't really relevant. I've removed it.

Comment: What term are you trying to define? Take the example $6/3=2$ - are you trying to describe $6,3$ or $2$?

Comment: I will be more careful with the tags I use @AlfredYerger. Thank you all for the feedback.

Comment: @JohnDoe I am trying to describe 2.

Comment: @Jeff I would say that $2$ is a quotient of $6$

Comment: @Jeff I guess that another possible reason for the downvote would be the confusion I highlighted above then. As for your actual question, if a fraction $\frac ab$ gives an integer as an answer, then you say $b$ divides $a$. If not, then $b$ does not divide $a$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard terminologies for "there is an integer $k$ such that $a=kb$" are

- $b$ divides (or "is a divisor of") $a$
- $a$ is a multiple of $b$

In symbols, you typically see $b\mid a$.

Comment: I guess the same things you say for $b$ can be said for $k$.

Answer (score 4):

If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $b=ak$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then we write $a|b$ and say $a$ **[divides](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divides.html)** $b$.